# if no entries in events, then do NOT show in Sidemenu in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am fetching data from API and displaying it in the flutter app.
In API data is like event id, event name, start date. I am able to display all the things. I am using Sidemenu in that "event" is one item.
My question is if there is no data in API then I do not want the "event" field in sidemenu.

I am using the below code in the sidebar

```
onTapEvents(BuildContext context) {
Navigator.push(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => EventsScreen()),
);  }
```

any suggestion will help me
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should try this `onTapped` function:

```
onTapped: () {
    Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => EventsScreen()),
    );  
}
```

Comment: when I am trying to use the above code I am getting errors.
I am using the different templates in the app and also using the below code

_buildEntry(
                    context,
                    Translations.of(context).text("events"),
                    () => onTapEvents(context),
                  ),